# Rails query where at least 1 of the associated records contains an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `GroupMeetings` table and a `GroupMeetingsUser` table which is a join table between `User` and `GroupMeetings`. I want to find all the GroupMeetings where at least 1 of the GroupMeetingsUser has an attribute.

Right now, this works:

```
   @group_meetings = GroupMeeting.where('lang_one_id IN (?) AND lang_two_id IN (?) AND meeting_time >= ?', @user.languages.pluck(:id), @user.languages.pluck(:id), Date.today)

   @new_group_meetings_id = []

   @group_meetings.each do |meeting|
     meeting.group_meetings_user.each do |user|
       if(user.user.location === @user.location)
         @new_group_meetings_id.push(meeting.id)
       end
     end
   end

   @group_meetings = GroupMeeting.where('id IN (?)', @new_group_meetings_id)
```

But how can I include the `.each` loop in original GroupMeetings query instead? Like using `.joins(:group_meetings_user)` to find all the records where at least 1 of the users has an attribute?

```
class GroupMeeting < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :group_meetings_users
    has_many :users, through: :group_meetings_users
end

class GroupMeetingsUser < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group_meeting

    validates_presence_of :user_id, :group_meeting_id
    validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :group_meeting_id, :message => 'can only join each group once.'}
end
```

UPDATE 1:

`GroupMeeting.joins(:users).where(group_meeting: { lang_one_id: @user.languages.pluck(:id), lang_two_id: @user.languages.pluck(:id), meeting_time: DateTime.now..DateTime::Infinity.new}, user: { location: @user.location })`

gives the error:

`no such column: group_meeting.lang_one_id: SELECT "group_meetings".* FROM "group_meetings" INNER JOIN "group_meetings_users" ON "group_meetings_users"."group_meeting_id" = "group_meetings"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "group_meetings_users"."user_id" WHERE "group_meeting"."lang_one_id" IN (29, 30, 31, 22) AND "group_meeting"."lang_two_id" IN (29, 30, 31, 22) AND ("group_meeting"."meeting_time" >= ?) AND "user"."location" = ?`

Comment: try `GroupMeeting.joins(:users).where(group_meeting: {  lang_one_id: @user.languages.pluck(:id), lang_two_id: @user.languages.pluck(:id), meeting_time: DateTime.now..DateTime::Infinity.new}, user: { location: @user.location })`

Comment: Oh I like that! How would I be able to do it like `GroupMeeting.joins(:users).where('group_meeting.lang_one_id IN (?) AND group_meeting.lang_two_id IN (?) AND group_meeting.meeting_time >= ? AND users.location = ?', @user.languages.pluck(:id), @user.languages.pluck(:id), Date.today, @user.location)`. I would like to use comparative operators, like `>= ` in the query for both group_meetings and users

Comment: @fanta I updated the question with the error from that suggested query

Comment: update the query I used with `.where(group_meetings: { ...)`

Comment: Ah yes that worked! And I also had to update `user` to `users`

Comment: This works now as well: `GroupMeeting.joins(:users).where('group_meetings.lang_one_id IN (?) AND group_meetings.lang_two_id IN (?) AND group_meetings.meeting_time >= ? AND users.location = ?', @user.languages.pluck(:id), @user.languages.pluck(:id), Date.today, @user.location)` Want to post a solution below, and I'll accept. Thanks so much :))

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

```
GroupMeeting
  .joins('INNER JOIN languages l1 ON languages l1.id = group_meetings.lang_one_id')
  .joins('INNER JOIN languages l2 ON languages l2.id = group_meetings.lang_two_id')
  .joins(:group_meeting_users => :users)
  .where('meeting_time >= ?', Date.today)
  .select('group_meetings.*')
  .group('group_meetings.id')
  .having('users.location = ?', @user.location)
```

It should be faster than doing sub-selects (using `languages.id IN (?)` and `pluck`)

Let me know if that works and/or if you have questions.